Unable to get dynamic list in jelastic script menifest
I am working on setting up a dynamic value for a dropdown. Currently, I am using a static JSON to populate it, but I plan to replace the static JSON with a dynamic script. However, I am facing an issue where I am unable to set the JSON values into the dropdown using this script.
When i am setting static dropdown it's working. The issue is with dynamic value only. i am just getting 1 as list value
type: update
name: Test Add-On
id: test-schedule
logo: /images/schedule-logo.png
description: Test Add-On for schedule functionality.

targetNodes:
  nodeGroup:
    - bl
    - cp

globals:
  bckDates: []

onInstall:
  - getbckDates

actions:
  getbckDates:
    - script: |
        var dates = [];
        
        dates = [
            {
                value: "",
                caption: "Select date"
            },
            {
                value: "2024-10-01",
                caption: "2024-10-01"
            },
            {
                value: "2024-10-02",
                caption: "2024-10-02"
            }
        ];        
        
        return { 
            result: 0,
            bckDates: dates
        };
    - setGlobals:
        bckDates: ${response.bckDates}

settings:
  schedule:
    fields:
      - type: list
        name: bckDates
        caption: Select schedule Date
        required: true
        width: 300
        values: 
          - value: ""
            caption: "Loading schedule dates..."
          - script: |
              var resp = api.getResponse();
              if (resp && resp.bckDates && Array.isArray(resp.bckDates)) {
                  return resp.bckDates;
              }
              return [
                  {value: "", caption: "Select schedule date"},
                  {value: "error", caption: "Failed to load schedule dates"}
              ];

buttons:
  - caption: DateList
    action: schedule
    loadingText: scheduling process...
    settings: schedule
    successText: successfully setup done.
    title: Schedule Done
    submitButtonText: Start Schedule

